# Locale and Command line input

Tags: java

I have started to work with Locale in Java 1.5 in Eclipse, and I want to write in the Command line to change the current Locale.

Command: locale en_US

Result : locale changed to en_US

Command: Quit

How do I get my command in the command line to trigger my method(s)?

-Mike

Comment: Well, let's take a look at what code you have now and we can move on from there :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about something like this:

```
java -Duser.country=ES -Duser.language=es -Duser.variant=Traditional_WIN -jar <jar name>.jar
```

Here is a link for more code examples: http://www.exampledepot.com/egs/java.util/SetDefLocale.html

Is this what you were looking for?